# changing Rails check_box_tag to "checked" with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, onclick

The code for this is probably simple, but I'm not hot on Jquery yet and I couldn't find a solution online.

In my view, users need to be able to select from a variety of plant images using a rails check_box_tag form submit. When a user clicks on a plant image, I want its accompanying check box to become selected.

My view:

```
<%= form_for @project.prelationships.build(:pfollowed_id => @project_id) do |f| %>
  <% Plant.all.each do |plant| %>
    <h>
      <%= image_tag plant.image_path %>
      <%= check_box_tag "prelationship[pfollower_id][]", plant.id %>
    </h>
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, @project.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Pfollow" %>
<% end %>
```

And in my application.js:

```
$(function () {
  $("h").click(function () {
    $(this).hide().parent().find(':submit').click();
  });
});
```

The problem with that javascript code right now is that it submits the form when you click on an image instead of simply checking off that image's checkbox. How do I modify that one line of code to return a checked checkbox on onclick? I've seen a lot of sample solutions online, but they have never dealt with rails' check_box_tag, which seems to require a unique answer.

Comment: Rails `check_box_tag` helper generates plain old checkbox input and doesn't require any special treatment. Though, it's not very clear for me why are you trying to find sibling tag by `:submit` selector and click on it when you need to find a child by `input[type='checkbox']` selector and check it with `.prop('checked', true)`. Btw, what kind of tag is `<h>`? Am I missing something or it should be `<h1>` or some other kind of header tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I guess what you mean this should solve it:

```
$(function() {       
    $("h").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

See it working at: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RZUfs/

Comment: Thanks, @David. That's what I was looking for. I just couldn't get the syntax right with my fledgling Javascript skills.